# How do I release an external drive after it's been accessed by my program?

Tags: vb.net

The VB.Net program in question creates several files, adds them into a zip file (using DotNetZip), and saves the zip file into a given directory (which the user chooses). This comes out just fine. But when I use it to save directly to my USB flash drive, I can't eject the drive without shutting down the program first.

I've tried disposing the zip object (from the DotNetZip library), doesn't work. I also tried setting FileIO.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory to somewhere else on the machine, still no.

Comment: ...and you are closing any file handles/streams?

Comment: Called StreamWriter.close after a try-catch block instead of in the Finally clause, and it worked. I thought that would always execute...Thanks for the comment, I would have been blissfully unaware otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In your last comment you've said that calling the 'Close' outside of the Try Catch sorted your problem, I'd recomend using a "Using" stament insted.  This will close/dispose of your StreamWriter 100% of the time no matter what happens.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx